# Leaflet import GeoJson

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet, geojson

I'm developing an angular application with leaflet and i have to show many municipality about my country:

[image]

To do this and make navigation efficient, i needed to split my json file in multiple files and put them in assets folder:

[image]

and to show layer in mai I'm using angular HttpClient in the following way:

```
this.http.get('assets/shp/Comuni.geojson').subscribe((json: any) => {
 L.geoJSON(this.json).addTo(map);
});
```

the size of my asset folder has become almost a gigabyte, and i need to store this files in a external repository, like a server. Any suggestion about this? What is the correct way to handle this kind to situation?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the geoJSON files to topoJSON which are way smaller than geojson and the conversion allows you to incrementally simplify a dataset.

To convert you can install topojson

`npm install -g topojson`

and convert it as follow

```
topojson -o topo.json geoJSON.json
```

This will save you a lot of size.

Comment: I tried to convert all my files using "geo2topo -o topo.json geoJSON.json", I have reduced the size but I still have about 500MB which is a lot to bring in my webapp

Comment: I see. Then we may need to host in a server as you mentioned. Because 500 is getting too much :) But I was expecting topoJSON would help you more than that.

Comment: What types of servers do you recommend to use?

Answer (score 0):

I bet it's something wrong with yours geoJson files. Maybe they are overdetalized.
For example [look at Canada.geojson](https://github.com/codeforamerica/click_that_hood/blob/master/public/data/canada.geojson) it has size near 400 kb for whole the second largest country in the world.
You can try service like https://mapshaper.org/ to simply your data.

Comment: I know that my files are overdetalized, but i need to show smaller parts of a municipality, and the i need to this detail.

Answer (score 0):

> and i need to store this files in a external repository, like a server. Any suggestion about this?
>
> [...]
>
> I know that my files are overdetalized, but i need to show smaller
> parts of a municipality, and the i need to this detail.

Well, there are 2 approaches. And it mainly has to do with the type of data you want to receive in the front-end. You want vector data (e.g. GeoJSON)? Or maybe raster tiles (e.g. WMS)?

**1st approach - Vector Data**

You definitely cannot store/load all your data at once. You should store them at an external server and get more data with appropriate requests. For example, you could initially only load a simplified GeoJSON for all municipalities in a low zoom level, and when the user chooses / pans to a certain municipality, request from the server a GeoJSON with higher detail. However, developing a pyramid-like structure for multiple zoom levels etc, would not be easy. So, you have to consider if this approach can work in your case.

**2st approach - Raster Data**

You can forget about GeoJSON and develop a GeoServer. http://geoserver.org/
You will have all your spatial data in the back-end and choose to serve only raster tiles in your front-end using e.g. a WMS. It may sound like extra hassle but on the other hand, you will not have to worry about oversized GeoJSONs etc.

Comment: 1st approach is perfectly what i did, but in this moment i stored/loaded my files in assets folder and my webapp is becoming too big. Can i use GeoServer to store also geoJson file? Are there others server can i use or I have to create a homemade server? thanks

Comment: If 1st approach works for you, then you should just store your files in an external server instead of your app assets folder. Then, request the necessary file(s) with AJAX requests. With GeoServer, you can store JSON files (or other spatial formats) and, in your case, it would be better to server them as raster tiles (think about the way you load OpenStreetMap).